# Querying the teradata to get the list of all the databases

Tags: java, c#, teradata

I query the Teradata database using `resultset` and `getmetadata`. For some reason I find it hard to get the result using C#.

This is the code in Java:

```
public class T20905JD
{
    public static String sUser = "guest";
    public static String sPassword = "please";

    public static void main(String args[])

    {
        // Creation of URL to be passed to the JDBC driver
        String url = "jdbc:teradata://whomooz/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8";

        // Creating a connection object
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, sUser, sPassword);
        System.out.println(" User " + sUser + " connected.");
        System.out.println(" Connection to Teradata established. \n");

        DatabaseMetaData dbmd = con.getMetaData();
        System.out.println(" DatabaseMetaData object created. \n");

        ResultSet rs = dbmd.getSchemas();

        // Display the database names
        System.out.println(" DISPLAYING ALL DATABASE NAMES:\n");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(" " + rs.getString("TABLE_SCHEM"));
        }
    }
}
```

How would I get the same result using C# in Teradata?

Comment: Improved question and code formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not related to C# nor Java, but Teradata. The easiest way to get all databases (schemata) is to query for:

```
SELECT DatabaseName, OwnerName
  FROM DBC.DATABASES
 WHERE DBKind = 'D';
```

If you would like to see the hierarchy of the databases, you have to include OwnerName into your query.

Comment: You may wish to use DBC.DatabasesV which supports UNICODE.